# Как определить ДДОС?

Tags: администрирование

Как отличить ДДОС-атаку от того, что просто висит сервер? Недавно очень было что-то похожее с одной стороны, а с другой стороны - кому бы понадобилось ддосить мой блог?

Comment: Посмотреть по логам?

Comment: @anton_n, если вы делите свой сервер с кем-то (если покупаете именно "хостинг", а не "сервер", то скорее всего так и есть), то все пользователи сервера делят между собой ресурсы, поэтому досить могли и кого-то другого.

Comment: да нет, не сервер, а просто хостинг. я имел в виду сервак, на котором хостинг висит

Answer (score 1):

Смотри на входящий траффик. Если запросы зашкаливают прямо аномально - это точно ДДОс. Меняй хостера или ставь нормальное ПО от таких траблов

Comment: а что, хостинг может быть с защитой от ддос-атак?

Comment: Конечно, может, только дорого обычно получается.
https://www.google.ru/search?ie=UTF-8&hl=ru&q=hosting%20ddos%20protection&gws_rd=ssl

Comment: Может, и должен, у меня на http://www.cishost.ru/ два сайта висят, за полтора года ничего подобного не было. У них серваки очень надежные.

Comment: понял, спасибо

Comment: @Джанго, а у людей другие мнения. http://hosting101.ru/cishost.ru

Comment: @Джанго, у них серваки надежные потому, что вас за два года никто не задел? Oh my.

Comment: Недовольные всегда будут. За пои полтора года сотрудничества с ними все было отлично и жаловаться не на что

Comment: @Джанго, ваш личный опыт физически не может отражать ситуацию целиком.

Answer (score 1):

Если у тебя shared хостинг, то стоит написать в техподдержку и спросить у них. Самому разбираться бессмысленно, т.к. что-либо исправить не хватит прав.